LVM - Couldn't find device with uuid
This is a VMware VM recovered by Veeam B&R, after that I try to boot the VM but appears some errors relating to missing PVs. This the thing:
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid TAa5ei-oJrz-t1Fs-a6dH-OCXf-cx23-JxNz8C.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid THwbYj-NsSV-8J0z-yCnD-E0Zg-hvss-LfGXN2.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid qYrust-yeOX-JUeb-sr2Y-mlqZ-VIeH-FRYP7r.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid EcvYcl-eDSC-gqVy-AVSe-EWe4-RN5J-Wc9YVQ.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid 44aGUQ-W8aD-XkGx-99hS-WHVZ-Lxjt-Tv5FeW.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid fh7OnQ-QaQ1-EqQr-LMwl-WGCk-1NiL-bqudMc.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid 0KsuZk-2dt8-RvBo-zmat-6vwh-iZev-iN5cIF.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid SIOoym-McVL-ZPec-XC8w-ZUy9-relQ-YevLSV.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid 1VKrRt-X1er-CIPW-rfBR-GxGQ-AyDX-uQNoeq.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid jZWzHw-rIbD-s0uz-DEAn-DSm6-IMlq-pv46iJ.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid r6zuEy-uU2x-SwSq-G9Vt-KOZa-FUQQ-clNhIS.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid TNhC6d-HAu3-XJTy-vLvr-g4Ik-ZeE1-2YLghx.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid ZOCVnd-0xXl-0G2C-T3ql-5Ijv-v23T-5tQpCK.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid hnWk0G-aHUw-cT8f-OSzK-sYn9-s6lL-4u5fbf.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid c8K3rc-V4tv-TR3n-lY7j-ZjGg-LjFP-VMHx4e.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid eETvWd-F3Kd-Pu10-dUon-fnIr-DLux-pvADc9.
  WARNING: PV /dev/sda3 in VG VolGroup00 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
  WARNING: PV /dev/sda5 in VG VolGroup00 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
  WARNING: PV /dev/sdi1 in VG VolGroup00 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
  WARNING: PV /dev/sdo1 in VG VolGroup00 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
  WARNING: PV /dev/sdp in VG VolGroup00 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV TAa5ei-oJrz-t1Fs-a6dH-OCXf-cx23-JxNz8C (last written to /dev/sdb1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV THwbYj-NsSV-8J0z-yCnD-E0Zg-hvss-LfGXN2 (last written to /dev/sdc1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV qYrust-yeOX-JUeb-sr2Y-mlqZ-VIeH-FRYP7r (last written to /dev/sdd1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV EcvYcl-eDSC-gqVy-AVSe-EWe4-RN5J-Wc9YVQ (last written to /dev/sdf1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV 44aGUQ-W8aD-XkGx-99hS-WHVZ-Lxjt-Tv5FeW (last written to /dev/sde1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV fh7OnQ-QaQ1-EqQr-LMwl-WGCk-1NiL-bqudMc (last written to /dev/sdh1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV 0KsuZk-2dt8-RvBo-zmat-6vwh-iZev-iN5cIF (last written to /dev/sdi1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV SIOoym-McVL-ZPec-XC8w-ZUy9-relQ-YevLSV (last written to /dev/sdj1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV 1VKrRt-X1er-CIPW-rfBR-GxGQ-AyDX-uQNoeq (last written to /dev/sdk).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV jZWzHw-rIbD-s0uz-DEAn-DSm6-IMlq-pv46iJ (last written to /dev/sdl).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV r6zuEy-uU2x-SwSq-G9Vt-KOZa-FUQQ-clNhIS (last written to /dev/sdo1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV TNhC6d-HAu3-XJTy-vLvr-g4Ik-ZeE1-2YLghx (last written to /dev/sdp1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV ZOCVnd-0xXl-0G2C-T3ql-5Ijv-v23T-5tQpCK (last written to /dev/sdq).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV hnWk0G-aHUw-cT8f-OSzK-sYn9-s6lL-4u5fbf (last written to /dev/sdr).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV c8K3rc-V4tv-TR3n-lY7j-ZjGg-LjFP-VMHx4e (last written to /dev/sds1).
  WARNING: VG VolGroup00 is missing PV eETvWd-F3Kd-Pu10-dUon-fnIr-DLux-pvADc9 (last written to /dev/sdt1).


The content of /etc/lvm/VolGroup00_00000-815974025.vg is:
`# Generated by LVM2 version 2.03.21(2) (2023-04-21): Wed Jul 31 15:00:31 2024

contents = "Text Format Volume Group"
version = 1

description = "Created *before* executing 'vgs --noheadings --nosuffix --nameprefixes --unquoted --units=b -o name,uuid,size,free,extent_size,extent_count,free_count,pv_count '--config= log {level=7 file=/tmp/lvm.log syslog=0}' --devices=/dev/sda3'"

creation_host = "localhost.localdomain" # Linux localhost.localdomain 5.14.0-362.8.1.el9_3.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Nov 8 17:36:32 UTC 2023 x86_64
creation_time = 1722438031  # Wed Jul 31 15:00:31 2024

VolGroup00 {
    id = "Qdx1Y7-LbwR-OJxa-2t87-A7mA-LxDd-fc3INj"
    seqno = 56
    format = "lvm2"         # informational
    status = ["RESIZEABLE", "READ", "WRITE"]
    flags = []
    extent_size = 65536     # 32 Megabytes
    max_lv = 0
    max_pv = 0
    metadata_copies = 0

    physical_volumes {

        pv0 {
            id = "iIIMZD-KJt0-3eKB-k3qc-SDlB-D9wN-Tu2cDB"
            device = "/dev/sda3"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = []
            dev_size = 620542371    # 295.898 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 9468 # 295.875 Gigabytes
        }

        pv1 {
            id = "TAa5ei-oJrz-t1Fs-a6dH-OCXf-cx23-JxNz8C"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 104856192    # 49.9993 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 1599 # 49.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv2 {
            id = "iHQ0O7-2Ebt-1ua1-kIJw-Usgu-cy2g-fOcpYs"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 104856192    # 49.9993 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 1599 # 49.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv3 {
            id = "THwbYj-NsSV-8J0z-yCnD-E0Zg-hvss-LfGXN2"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 524280828    # 249.997 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 7999 # 249.969 Gigabytes
        }

        pv4 {
            id = "qYrust-yeOX-JUeb-sr2Y-mlqZ-VIeH-FRYP7r"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 524280828    # 249.997 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 7999 # 249.969 Gigabytes
        }

        pv5 {
            id = "EcvYcl-eDSC-gqVy-AVSe-EWe4-RN5J-Wc9YVQ"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 629137467    # 299.996 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 9599 # 299.969 Gigabytes
        }

        pv6 {
            id = "44aGUQ-W8aD-XkGx-99hS-WHVZ-Lxjt-Tv5FeW"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209712447    # 99.9987 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv7 {
            id = "VPI6vR-2fHA-nbQa-UAkx-O6mQ-HVmb-4M8omx"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 115330572    # 54.9939 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 1759 # 54.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv8 {
            id = "fh7OnQ-QaQ1-EqQr-LMwl-WGCk-1NiL-bqudMc"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 419424957    # 199.997 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 6399 # 199.969 Gigabytes
        }

        pv9 {
            id = "0KsuZk-2dt8-RvBo-zmat-6vwh-iZev-iN5cIF"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 1048562487   # 499.994 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 15999    # 499.969 Gigabytes
        }

        pv10 {
            id = "SIOoym-McVL-ZPec-XC8w-ZUy9-relQ-YevLSV"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 1048562487   # 499.994 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 15999    # 499.969 Gigabytes
        }

        pv11 {
            id = "1VKrRt-X1er-CIPW-rfBR-GxGQ-AyDX-uQNoeq"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209715200    # 100 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv12 {
            id = "jZWzHw-rIbD-s0uz-DEAn-DSm6-IMlq-pv46iJ"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209715200    # 100 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv13 {
            id = "c7uAOZ-FA93-qgy4-RVXx-7moC-pYwK-QTkIiw"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209712447    # 99.9987 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv14 {
            id = "2nYU3z-U6hp-Hm71-HhbP-IlS0-Onis-4opu4S"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 419430400    # 200 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 6399 # 199.969 Gigabytes
        }

        pv15 {
            id = "r6zuEy-uU2x-SwSq-G9Vt-KOZa-FUQQ-clNhIS"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209712447    # 99.9987 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv16 {
            id = "TNhC6d-HAu3-XJTy-vLvr-g4Ik-ZeE1-2YLghx"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209712447    # 99.9987 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv17 {
            id = "ZOCVnd-0xXl-0G2C-T3ql-5Ijv-v23T-5tQpCK"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209715200    # 100 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv18 {
            id = "hnWk0G-aHUw-cT8f-OSzK-sYn9-s6lL-4u5fbf"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209715200    # 100 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv19 {
            id = "c8K3rc-V4tv-TR3n-lY7j-ZjGg-LjFP-VMHx4e"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 209712447    # 99.9987 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes
        }

        pv20 {
            id = "eETvWd-F3Kd-Pu10-dUon-fnIr-DLux-pvADc9"
            device = "[unknown]"    # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = ["MISSING"]
            dev_size = 1048562487   # 499.994 Gigabytes
            pe_start = 384
            pe_count = 15999    # 499.969 Gigabytes
        }
    }

    logical_volumes {

        root {
            id = "fj0MoK-hmUH-viTe-QaD1-VYA0-vVBU-Eu8xzF"
            status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
            flags = []
            segment_count = 5

            segment1 {
                start_extent = 0
                extent_count = 9468 # 295.875 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv0", 0
                ]
            }
            segment2 {
                start_extent = 9468
                extent_count = 1599 # 49.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv1", 0
                ]
            }
            segment3 {
                start_extent = 11067
                extent_count = 1599 # 49.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv2", 0
                ]
            }
            segment4 {
                start_extent = 12666
                extent_count = 1599 # 49.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv3", 0
                ]
            }
            segment5 {
                start_extent = 14265
                extent_count = 1569 # 49.0312 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv4", 0
                ]
            }
        }

        alfresco {
            id = "pRzFfr-ej3P-fZ7l-tHSQ-sE4b-qPBG-LkxZBP"
            status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
            flags = []
            segment_count = 20

            segment1 {
                start_extent = 0
                extent_count = 9599 # 299.969 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv5", 0
                ]
            }
            segment2 {
                start_extent = 9599
                extent_count = 30   # 960 Megabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv4", 1569
                ]
            }
            segment3 {
                start_extent = 9629
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv6", 0
                ]
            }
            segment4 {
                start_extent = 12828
                extent_count = 1759 # 54.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv7", 0
                ]
            }
            segment5 {
                start_extent = 14587
                extent_count = 6399 # 199.969 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv8", 0
                ]
            }
            segment6 {
                start_extent = 20986
                extent_count = 15999    # 499.969 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv9", 0
                ]
            }
            segment7 {
                start_extent = 36985
                extent_count = 6400 # 200 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv3", 1599
                ]
            }
            segment8 {
                start_extent = 43385
                extent_count = 6400 # 200 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv4", 1599
                ]
            }
            segment9 {
                start_extent = 49785
                extent_count = 15999    # 499.969 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv10", 0
                ]
            }
            segment10 {
                start_extent = 65784
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv11", 0
                ]
            }
            segment11 {
                start_extent = 68983
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv12", 0
                ]
            }
            segment12 {
                start_extent = 72182
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv13", 0
                ]
            }
            segment13 {
                start_extent = 75381
                extent_count = 6368 # 199 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv14", 0
                ]
            }
            segment14 {
                start_extent = 81749
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv15", 0
                ]
            }
            segment15 {
                start_extent = 84948
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv16", 0
                ]
            }
            segment16 {
                start_extent = 88147
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv17", 0
                ]
            }
            segment17 {
                start_extent = 91346
                extent_count = 31   # 992 Megabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv14", 6368
                ]
            }
            segment18 {
                start_extent = 91377
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv18", 0
                ]
            }
            segment19 {
                start_extent = 94576
                extent_count = 3199 # 99.9688 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv19", 0
                ]
            }
            segment20 {
                start_extent = 97775
                extent_count = 15999    # 499.969 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv20", 0
                ]
            }
        }
    }

}

And the fdisk shows this:
Disk /dev/sda: 350 GiB, 375809638400 bytes, 734003200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000d8061

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *           63    208844    208782 101.9M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2          208845   8594774   8385930     4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3         8594775 629137529 620542755 295.9G 8e Linux LVM
/dev/sda4       629137530 733993784 104856255    50G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       629137593 733993784 104856192    50G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdb: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdd: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sde: 250 GiB, 268435456000 bytes, 524288000 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdf: 250 GiB, 268435456000 bytes, 524288000 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdg: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdh: 300 GiB, 322122547200 bytes, 629145600 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdi: 55 GiB, 59055800320 bytes, 115343360 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdi1          63 115330634 115330572  55G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdj: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdk: 500 GiB, 536870912000 bytes, 1048576000 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdl: 500 GiB, 536870912000 bytes, 1048576000 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdm: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdn: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdo: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdo1          63 209712509 209712447  100G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdp: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdq: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I know this is a crappy mess, but I don't know that to do to recover every disk/partition to PV. Can you help me?

What is the output of lsblk and blkid? What was the layout before it went this way, remember as much as you can? What was done to the system so it went this way; again, try to remember as much as you can? // Also try asking Veeam support for explanations — this is paid software, they have to work off the money you paid for it.
